# Centralized script for multiple spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have created a Notification script and would like to use it for multiple spreadsheets (produced by Forms). I would like to have a centralized script and referencing it on my multiple spreadsheets in order to simplify maintenance.

I have tried to use the `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` like below but looks like this feature has been disabled for security reasons and is not supported anymore.

```
function append()
{
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("1xdePF..........................");
}
```

Any idea on how to use the same script for multiple spreadsheets?

Comment: There were no deprecations of `openById` as far as I recall. Please, provide us with how `oauthScopes` manifest field looks like (or if you authorized it manually), exact issue (is there an error? If so, what the msg says) and what "referencing" means (as a library?)

Comment: I authorized it manually, error message is Exception: Document 1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxA2ZN is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or maybe you don't have read access?) (line 3, file "Code"). Referencing means calling an App script.

Comment: `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` has not been disabled, but you are only allowed to open spreadsheets if you are its the owner or it has been shared with you. The spreadsheet id usually contains 44 characters. Also, are you calling your function `append()` on a trigger?

Comment: Christian - please, be more specific about calling context - it is important. In addition to ziganotschka's comment - is this "maintenance" script [standalone](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone)?

Comment: Yes I am the owner of the spreadsheets. In fact it is a script and not a spreadsheet I want to access. Id was obtained using File Properties and has 58 characters. I am calling my function in a script created from a sheet using Tools and script edit.

Answer (score 1):

### The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) specifies that `openById` opens the **spreadsheet** with the given ID.

You cannot use this method to open a script.

To open an Apps Script, go to https://script.google.com/home/my and clock on the script of your choice.

For bound scripts, you open the document to which the script is bound and go to `Tools->Script Editor`

Answer (score 0):

**Preface**

This answer is supplementary to ziganotschka's, since you indeed cannot access the script bound to a document by opening said document with `openById()`. The answer, instead, covers other issues you had and suggests additional ways to solve your task.

**Problem**

When trying to use `openById()` you receive an error message of the following structure:

> Exception: Document [doc id here] is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or maybe you don't have read access?)

You mentioned in comments that the id is 58 chars (I bit it is 57) and obtained from "properties", which explains the error - there is no spreadsheet with such an id, because *file id* and *script id* you extracted are not the same thing. If you ever need to extract *current* id programmatically (here it is assumed to be called from a script bound to spreadsheet, but other services have similar methods), you can call `getActiveSpreadsheet()` -> `getId()`.

**Solutions**

You stated that you need a *maintenance* script, so how about creating a standalone script project that is deployed in a way *any* document can access:

*As a library*

Any script that has a saved *version* can be a library that can be used by other scripts by adding its id to the list accessible from `Resources->Libraries` menu.

*As a Web App*

Any script that has a `doGet`, `doPost` function (or both) can be deployed as a Web App, essentially exposing it to the net. Since you said that the spreadsheets are "produced" by Forms, and you created a "notification" script, I assume you are interested in a `FormSubmit` event. When you deploy as a Web App, you get a *url* (don't forget to choose an [appropriate permission](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#permissions)).

After that, it is only a matter of making sure that:

1. each Form has an installable `onFormSubmit` trigger (you can instlall it via [please see refs for docs] `ScriptApp.newTrigger('callback name').forForm('form ref').onFormSubmit()`).
2. The callback for the trigger calls the Web App url via `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` with necessary data (like spreadsheet id or any other info) as *query* (if using `doGet`) or request *body* (if using `doPost`).
3. The data you need will be available in the event object constructed on hit to `doGet` or `doPost` [note to avoid common misconception: you can't debug event objects in the editor, it can only be done live].

**Reference**

1. `getActiveSpreadsheet()` [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet)
2. `getId()` [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getid)
3. `getFileById()` [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFileById(String))
4. Standalone scripts [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone)
5. Bound scripts [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound)
6. Libraries [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)
7. Form submit event [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)
8. `new Trigger()` [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder)
9. `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))
10. `doGet` / `doPost` event object [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters)

Comment: Perfect thanks, I was doing wrong and have managed to get it work using library.